# FFMPEG -t outputs more length than it should?

Tags: ffmpeg

When I run this command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i 
"color=color=black@0.0:size=1080x1080,format=rgba,subtitles=../content/test/test.ssa:alpha=1" 
-c:a aac -c:v png -t "00:00:13.4" -threads 0 "../content/test/test.ssa.mov" -stats
```

And load the resulting mov file into any video editor, I get the length

```
00:00:13:10
```

I have a couple of hundredths of milliseconds of black (empty) space at the end of the video. What am I missing here?

I'm gonna include the SSA file here, so it's a bit more clear:

```
[Script Info]
ScriptType: v4.00
PlayResX: 960
PlayResY: 540
PlayDepth: 0
Timer: 100.0

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,24,&H00FFFFFF,&HFF000000,&HFF000000,&HFF000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0.00,3,0,0,5,100,100,100,1

Dialogue: 0,00:00:00.00,00:00:13.400,Default,,0,0,0,,Testing
```

Answer (score 0):

Most ffmpeg source filters default to 25 fps, and so does the color filter in your command. Your duration specification ends in `.4` which is 400 milliseconds. The `:10` in your editor represents the duration tail as a frame count. For 25 fps, 10 frames is 400 milliseconds. The output is exact as per your `-t`.

For empty space at the end, check your subtitle file for the end time of the last entry.

Comment: I have included the SSA file as well in my question. You'll see that everything is 13.400 (inside the SSA, in my command), and still I have a couple of milliseconds of empty (dark) frames. When I change the SSA end to 14 seconds, and keep the ffmpeg command on 13.4, there is no gap. I also checked the resulting file, it's 25fps.

Comment: This looks to be a subtitle filter issue, possibly a bug. Try a SSA file with gaps between subs and check if the subs do disappear at those gaps.